# Reactjs component hierarchy visualisation (tree view)

Tags: reactjs

i'm using the chrome extension "React-Sight" to get a live view of my react application component tree. but some timesit doesn't work

i'm searching for a better extension or better npm package that can replace "react-sight"

In fact i found "REACT-MONOCLE" but i don't know how to use it 
any help on how use "REACT-MONOCLE" or if you have any other extension on NPM module .

Comment: If you're using webpack, checkout webpack-bundle-analyzer. It's pretty neat and also shows size of each module and library.

Comment: Isn't React Developer Tools browser plugin enough?

Comment: No ain't enough i want to see the component tree hirarchey